# imputing bool into my .h

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have in my .h file saying

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIAccelerometerDelegate> {UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;

float xoff;
float yoff;
float xvelocity;
float yvelocity;
float xaccel;
float yaccel;
}
```

but I would want to put this code in my .h saying

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    BOOL FrontCamera;
    BOOL haveImage;
    UIImageView *capturedImage;

}
```

However I do not know how to put combine this to my current .h since i will be duplicating @interface ViewController twice.  How do you put this together?

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this ?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIAccelerometerDelegate> {

UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;

float xoff;
float yoff;
float xvelocity;
float yvelocity;
float xaccel;
float yaccel;

BOOL FrontCamera;
    BOOL haveImage;
    UIImageView *capturedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple!! Just take all variables and put them together in same interface.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIAccelerometerDelegate> 
{
    UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;
    float xoff;
    float yoff;
    float xvelocity;
    float yvelocity;
    float xaccel;
    float yaccel;

    BOOL FrontCamera;
    BOOL haveImage;
    UIImageView *capturedImage;
}
```

You can't create two interface with same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can put then in separate files using Categories. Objective-C Categories are a great option to split up the code into related parts or add something later.